# when refreshing page, php UPDATE sending to MYSQL empty parameter

Tags: php, mysqli

this code on click submit UPDATE user email and name, but when I refresh the page in the browser this code sending an empty string to MySQL, I mean after the refreshing page or browser column name and email in MySQL become empty,

```
   $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$userid=$ss['user']['id'];




$sql="UPDATE table_users SET name = '$name', email = '$email' WHERE user_id='$userid'     ";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "----1 record added";

mysqli_close
```

Comment: Your question is difficult to parse. Could you clean it up a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to this

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
  if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
}
```

you are not checking wheather the value in post is set or not.

Comment: do I need to keep mysqli_close

Comment: yeah you can add mysqli_close inside the isset